# How to do polygon fills for KMLs with GDAL/OGR

Tags: python, gdal, kml, ogr

I'm trying to create a filled polygon in Python with osgeo. When I set the polygon edge and fill with .SetStyleString(), PEN successfully sets the polygon outline colour, but BRUSH does not fill it. (Brush parameters are defined in [section 2.4 of this specification](http://www.gdal.org/ogr_feature_style.html).)

Here's my code:

```
from osgeo import ogr

# Create ring
ring = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbLinearRing)
ring.AddPoint(5.9559111595, 45.8179931641)
ring.AddPoint(10.4920501709, 45.8179931641)
ring.AddPoint(10.4920501709, 47.808380127)
ring.AddPoint(5.9559111595, 47.808380127)
ring.AddPoint(5.9559111595, 45.8179931641)

# Create polygon
poly = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPolygon)
poly.AddGeometry(ring)

# output a KML
# (via examples on https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/geometry.html)
outDriver = ogr.GetDriverByName('KML')
outDataSource = outDriver.CreateDataSource('output.kml')
outLayer = outDataSource.CreateLayer('output.kml',geom_type=ogr.wkbPolygon)
featureDefn = outLayer.GetLayerDefn()
outFeature = ogr.Feature(featureDefn)
outFeature.SetGeometry(poly)
outFeature.SetStyleString("BRUSH(fc:#FF0000FF);PEN(c:#00FF00FF)")
outLayer.CreateFeature(outFeature)
outFeature = None
outDataSource = None
```

And here is the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Document id="root_doc">
<Folder><name>output.kml</name>
  <Placemark>
    <Style><LineStyle><color>FF00FF00</color></LineStyle><PolyStyle><fill>0</fill></PolyStyle></Style>
      <Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>5.9559111595,45.8179931641,0 10.4920501709,45.8179931641,0 10.4920501709,47.808380127,0 5.9559111595,47.808380127,0 5.9559111595,45.8179931641,0</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>
  </Placemark>
</Folder>
</Document></kml>
```

This should create a KML polygon with a green border and red fill. A successful result would have this line:

```
<Style><LineStyle><color>FF00FF00</color></LineStyle><PolyStyle><color>FF0000FF</color><fill>1</fill></PolyStyle></Style>
```

I'm not sure how to tell GDAL that the polygon should be filled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that you used the KML driver https://www.gdal.org/drv_kml.html which is rather limited in capabilities. Use the LIBKML driver https://www.gdal.org/drv_libkml.html instead.

I verified with ogr2ogr (GDAL 2.4.0dev) that KML driver writes

```
<Style><LineStyle><color>FF00FF00</color></LineStyle><PolyStyle><fill>0</fill></PolyStyle></Style>
```

but LIBKML driver writes

```
<Style>
     <LineStyle>
        <color>ff00ff00</color>
        <width>1</width>
     </LineStyle>
     <PolyStyle>
        <color>ff0000ff</color>
     </PolyStyle>
 </Style>
```

The latter shows also as a filled polygon with Google Earth.

Answer (score 0):

I was also unable to create the polygon fill using the "KML" driver in ogr2ogr, but was able to use a workaround (text-editing the KML afterwards).

Process:
 **1. Create KML via ogr2ogr in the OSGeo4W Shell:**
 `ogr2ogr -a_srs epsg:3005 -f "KML" X:\test.kml OCI:user/password@DATABASE:junk -sql @X:\style.sql -dsco NameField="FIRE_NUMBER" -nln "wildfires" -progress`
The string above is me creating a KML from a database source (hence the OCI:) via an SQL file.

The desired KML formatting (PEN color and width, and BRUSH a.k.a. fill color) is contained within that SQL file, by creating a field called OGR_STYLE:
  `select fires.FIRE_NUMBER, fires.SHAPE, 'PEN(c:#8B0000,w:8px);BRUSH(c:#FA8072)' as OGR_STYLE`

Because the 'KML' driver sorta sucks, it only applies the PEN color. To get the fill, I first executed the ogr2ogr (to create the KML), then manually edited the .kml file in a text editor:

**2. Edit KML in a code editor:**
I used Sublime Text, but Visual Studio Code or any code editor that highlights markdown syntax will work. In the Document section, I created this Style:
`<Style id="fireStyle">
                <PolyStyle>
                    <color>7f0000ff</color>
                    <colorMode>normal</colorMode>
                </PolyStyle>
</Style>`

Then I applied this style to each placemark, by doing a find/replace in Sublime Text to get rid of any LineStyle / PolyStyle applied via ogr and manually replacing all that with a Style tag:

`<Placemark>
    <name>N10002</name><styleUrl>#firStyle</styleUrl>`

This may be a little convoluted, but it does work!